# compile nginx 1.16.1 with ngx_stream_log_module

Tags: compiling, make, nginx, module

I want to compile Nginx 1.161.1 that contain `ngx_stream_log_module`, so I do it:

```
./configure --sbin-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx \
--conf-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf \
--pid-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid \
--with-pcre=../pcre-8.43 \
--with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11 \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-http_v2_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_flv_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-stream \
--with-threads \
--with-mail=dynamic \
--with-stream=dynamic \
--with-compat \
--with-stream_log_module=dynamic
```

But I have this error:

```
./configure: error: invalid option "--with-stream_log_module=dynamic"
```

when compile and make without `--with-stream_log_module=dynamic` I dont have error but only install `ngx_stream_module.so` in `/usr/local/nginx/modules/`

what is the problem?
thanks.